# KML Direction of Movement Line

Tags: kml, google-earth, worldwind

I've been working with NASA WorldWind and Google Earth.  I'm using a KML [placemark](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#placemarks) for the icon, and I'm hoping to replicate a Header/Leader Line in KML.  I want a leader line similar to how the DIRECTION_OF_MOVEMENT line works in WorldWind for it's implementation on 2525 symbology.  Basically, the line indicates the direction that the object is moving in and it stays pointing towards that heading no matter the orientation of the map as shown by the black line in the attached screenshot.  How can I replicate this using KML in Google Earth?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I can't ask for clarification in comments (I don't have enough reputation). I'm assuming that you are looking for a way to enter a heading and have Google Earth automatically point something in that direction, because currently to draw that line you have to calculate start and end coordinates for each heading line that you want to put down.

If that is the case, the only place I found that allowed me to specify heading was IconStyle. This is how I did it:

1. Create an icon that depicts your heading line pointing up so rotating it 0 degrees points north, such as a vertical line (using an icon has the added bonus of scaling as you zoom in and out on Google Earth)
2. Use Style and IconStyle to use the icon from step 1.
3. Use the Style in your Placemark, and add an additional Style to set the heading.

Here is an example implementation below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
    <Document>
        <Style id="headingexample">
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1625-vertical-line3.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#headingexample</styleUrl>
            <Style>
                <IconStyle>
                    <heading>135</heading>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-99.21,40.01</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Please check that it works before accepting, I did it all from memory :) If the heading doesn't work in the IconStyle tag in the inline style, you might have to move it back to the original Style definition, which is slightly more cumbersome workflow-wise, but still better than calculating the endpoint manually.

Comment: @dubdubdubdot Hey guys, not sure this works the same. It moves funny depending on the way you skew it. Look: NASA: http://i.imgur.com/1inWyy4.gif - and Google (Andrew's solution): http://i.imgur.com/Np1vZ4e.gif

Comment: Good point.  This is frustrating.  For my purposes the top down view is the most important, but the side view skewing is not ideal.

Comment: @dubdubdubdot I added a GIF of the result of coupling a placemarker icon with a line on my answer, could you check and let me know your impressions?

Comment: I do like that it stays "oriented" a better on tilt, the one downside is that you cannot see the heading line unless you are zoomed way in.  It looks like there are pluses and minuses to each approach -- with the line as a linestring, it is oriented better on tilt, but with the line as an icon it works more like Worldwind (except on tilt)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a custom floating place-mark coupled with a 3D track?

[See it working](https://i.imgur.com/wGXOKNY.gif).

[See the NASA Worldwind reference](https://i.imgur.com/1inWyy4.gif).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
    <Document>

        <!-- Icon -->
        <Style id="tactical_symbol_placemark">
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>4</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://i.imgur.com/EEhQcPj.png</href>
                </Icon>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <styleUrl>#tactical_symbol_placemark</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-114.19327,51.4292695,6000</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <!-- Line -->
        <Style id="track_line">
            <LineStyle>
                <color>FF000000</color>
                <width>5.0</width>
            </LineStyle>
        </Style>
        <Folder>
            <name>tactical_symbols</name>
            <Placemark>
                <name>testing-Placemark-2</name>
                <styleUrl>#track_line</styleUrl>
                <LineString>
                    <extrude>false</extrude>
                    <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                    <coordinates>-114.19827,51.279256,6000 -114.18827,51.579283,6000</coordinates>
                </LineString>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: This is kinda sorta what I'm after except I want the line to point in the direction that the track is heading  (for instance at 135 degrees from the north pole)

Comment: Yeah, just like that but with a leader line as shown in the WorldWind screenshot.